# Provided Schema does not match table

Tags: python, database, virtual-machine, schema, google-bigquery

I have a script that I am running successfully in a local machine (PyCharm). But when I am adding script to the VM, it is throwing me the error of:

```
Bad request. The provided schema does not match to the table schema. STRING changed to BYTES.
```

Does anyone know why it should happen? I mean, locally everything is working perfect, this issue is popping up when I want to run the file from VM.

I am using BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure why it was happening in VM and not local. But just added 2 lines of code to solve it.

```
        if isinstance(register_date, bytes):
            register_date = str(register_date).decode("utf-8")
```